# RuntimeError when using DataCollatorForLanguageModeling with MLM=True and batch_size>1

Tags: python, machine-learning, pytorch, huggingface-transformers

I am trying to use the `DataCollatorForLanguageModeling` class from Hugging Face Transformers to create a DataLoader for my custom dataset. I am encountering a RuntimeError when I set `mlm=True` and `batch_size>1`. Here is the code I am using:

```py
data_collator=DataCollatorForLanguageModeling(tokenizer=tokenizer, return_tensors="pt", 
    mlm=True)
dataset=SmilesDataset(X[0:15], tokenizer)
data_loader = DataLoader(dataset, batch_size=3, shuffle=True, collate_fn=data_collator)
for x in data_loader:
    print(x)
```

When I run this code, I get the following error:

```
RuntimeError: output with shape [3, 1, 32] doesn't match the broadcast shape [3, 3, 32]
```

Interestingly, it works fine when I set `mlm=False` and `batch_size>1`, or when I set `mlm=True` and `batch_size=1`. The issue seems to be specifically related to using `mlm=True` with a batch size larger than 1.

I have also tried using `DataCollatorWithPadding` and it works as expected, but I need to use `DataCollatorForLanguageModeling` for my use case.

Here's a summary of the combinations I tried and their respective outcomes:

- `mlm=False`, `batch_size=3`: Works fine, no errors.
- `mlm=True`, `batch_size=1`: Works fine, no errors.
- `mlm=True`, `batch_size=3`: Throws a RuntimeError related to shape mismatch.
  I was expecting the combination of `mlm=True` and `batch_size>1` to work without any issues, similar to the other cases. However, it results in a RuntimeError, which I am not sure how to fix.

Can anyone help me understand what is causing this error and how to fix it? Thanks in advance!